# Why does this regex with no special character match a longer string?

Tags: c#, regex

I am using this method to try find a match, in an example:

```
Regex.Match("A2-TS-OIL", "TS-OIL", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success;
```

I got a true result. I am confused. I think this should return false since there is no special characters in the pattern. If I use `".+TS-OIL"`, true should be returned (`.` for any and `+` for more than 1). How should I do to get what I need?

Comment: If you aren't planning on using the match value then you might just want to use .indexOf instead of a regular expression.

Answer (score 11):

A regex match doesn't have to start at begining of the input.  You might want:

```
^TS-OIL
```

if you want to only match at the start. Or:

```
^TS-OIL$
```

to prevent it matching TS-OIL-123.

`^` matches the start of the input, $ matches the end.

I believe there are some place where the `^` and `$` get added automatically (like web validation controls) but they're the exception.

btw, you could use:

```
Regex.IsMatch(...)
```

in this case to save a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want a match if the test string starts with your regular expression, then you need to indicate as such:

```
Regex.Match("A2-TS-OIL", "^TS-OIL", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success;
```

The `^` indicates that the match must start at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

There's an implicit .* at the beginning and end of the expression string. You need to use ^ and $ which represent the start and end of the string to override that.

Answer (score 0):

TS-OIL is a substring in your A2-TS-OIL.  So, it would generate a match.  You have the simplest match possible - literal substring.  If you want TS-OIL to not match, you could also try (?!^A2-)(TS-OIL), assuming that you don't want it to start with A2-, but other things might be desired.

Comment: Not quite. The regex for "contains TS-OIL and doesn't start with A2-" would be "^(?!A2-).*TS-OIL" or "(?<!^A2-)TS-OIL". But I think the OP was just expecting "TS-OIL" to act like "^TS-OIL$".